# Content script won't run?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Here is my `manifest.json`:

```
  {
    "name": "arbitrary",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "arbitrary",
    "content_scripts": [ 
        {
            "matches": ["http://*.gmail.com/*", "https://*.gmail.com/*"],
            "js": ["contentScript.js"]
        }
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

And here is my content script, `contentScript.js`:

```
alert("hello!");
console.log("hi there");
```

I have loaded the unpacked extension but when I open a gmail tab, the code does not run. There is no alert nor console message.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gmail.com` is basically a vanity URL for the real domain, `mail.google.com`. I had to change what URLs were matched in the `manifest.json` accordingly.